# sort multi dimension array based on date

Tags: php, sorting

i have dates and names in text form in file like

```
2-4-2020,bat
14-3-2020,ball
25-6-2019,purse
27-8-2019,rice
```

so i m trying to sort it in ascending order

```
<?php
$newdates=$mydates=array();    
$lines = file('n:/mydata.txt');    
foreach($lines as $data)
{
    $mydates[]=explode(',',$data);
}  

$countdates=count($mydates);    
for ($i=0;$i<$countdates;$i++){
    $chkdate=$mydates[$i][0];
    $currentdate=DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $chkdate)->format('d-m-Y');
    $mydates[$i][0]=$currentdate;
}  
array_multisort($mydates);
$newdates=$mydates;    
$file = fopen("n:/newdates.txt","w");
foreach ($newdates as $contentline)
{
    fputcsv($file,$contentline);
}    
fclose($file);
```

but its not sorting at all

Answer (score 0):

It might be done a little simpler. You need to use `usort()` and `strtotime()` functions.

Here is simplified example

```
$mydates= array(
    ['2-4-2020','bat'],
    ['14-3-2020','ball'],
    ['25-6-2019','purse'],
    ['27-8-2019','rice']
    );

usort($mydates, function($a,$b) {
    return strtotime($a[0]) > strtotime($b[0]);
});

foreach ($mydates as $contentline) {
    echo json_encode($contentline);
}
```

Comment: As OP is reading from a CSV and writing to another, it would probably be less confusing if you tried to emulate that rather than reading from an array and json encoding the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into an array using the `file` function. Then you can sort the array using `usort`:

```
$fileName = 'n:/mydata.txt';

$lines = file($fileName);

usort($lines, function($a, $b) {
    foreach (['a', 'b'] as $variable) {
        $parts = explode(',', $$variable);
        $$variable = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', $parts[0]);
    }

    return $a < $b ? -1 : 1;
});

file_put_contents(implode("\n", $lines), $fileName);
```

Comment: something wrong with the code /...i get $b; }); file_put_contents(implode("\n", $lines), $fileName); ?> on the screen

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. Probably you use an older version of PHP which doesn't support the spaceship operator. Updated the answer.

Comment: sort part is getting sorted some are not.

Comment: What kind of dates do you have set? maybe you have 2 different formats?

Comment: format is same file i m using code on is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-JkHv-Wd2_4UJrg41NAVMi0rit6wIM6z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I just tested it and it seems to be correctly sorted. Also, I did found a different format: `15-07-2020` which is `j-m-Y`

Comment: it overwrite in same file right? or a new one is created?

Comment: no in my screen here ...see the las tfour data 2019 date comes there. after sorting